# Multiple Databases in Django 1.0.2 with custom manager

Tags: django, django-models

I asked this in the users group with no response so i thought I would try here.
I am trying to setup a custom manager to connect to another database 
on the same server as my default mysql connection.  I have tried 
following the examples [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/5d8c73eb483029af/19b19ed79bbbfa0d) and [here](http://www.djangrrl.com/view/multiple-database-connection-a-simple-use-case/) but have had no luck.  I get an empty tuple when returning 
`MyCustomModel.objects.all()`.

Here is what I have in manager.py

```
from django.db import models 
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper 
from django.conf import settings 
class CustomManager(models.Manager): 
    """ 
    This Manager lets you set the DATABASE_NAME on a per-model basis. 
    """ 
    def __init__(self, database_name, *args, **kwargs): 
        models.Manager.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        self.database_name = database_name 
    def get_query_set(self): 
        qs = models.Manager.get_query_set(self) 
        qs.query.connection = self.get_db_wrapper() 
        return qs 
    def get_db_wrapper(self): 
        # Monkeypatch the settings file. This is not thread-safe! 
        old_db_name = settings.DATABASE_NAME 
        settings.DATABASE_NAME = self.database_name 
        wrapper = DatabaseWrapper() 
        wrapper._cursor(settings) 
        settings.DATABASE_NAME = old_db_name 
        return wrapper
```

and here is what I have in models.py:

```
from django.db import models 
from myproject.myapp.manager import CustomManager 
class MyCustomModel(models.Model): 
    field1  = models.CharField(max_length=765) 
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=765) 
    objects = CustomManager('custom_database_name') 
    class Meta: 
        abstract = True
```

But if I run `MyCustomModel.objects.all()` I get an empty list.

I am pretty new at this stuff so I am not sure if this works with 
1.0.2, I am going to look into the Manager code to see if I can figure 
it out but I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong here.

UPDATE:
This now in Django trunk and will be part of the 1.2 release
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: This violates some essential features of Django.  The single database connection is in your settings module.  What are you really trying to do?  You should consider other approaches rather than breaking Django.

Comment: If you look at the examples I am trying to use, one is from Adrian.  
I have a work around solution where I user a helper module and just override the save function in model, but this is a bit of a hack and I don't get any django benefits.  

If you have a suggestion on how to add multiple database support to an app please let me know.

Comment: Can you be a little more patient? There is a GSOC project going on right now that is adding multiple database support to Django.

Comment: Thanks ironfroggy, I can wait.  Guess I don't have much of an option though LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to speak to [Alex Gaynor](http://twitter.com/alex_gaynor) as he is adding MultiDB support and its pegged for possible release in [Django 1.2](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.2Features). I'm sure he would appreciate feedback and input from those that are going to be using MultiDB. There is discussions about it in the [django-developers](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers) mainling list. His MultiDB branch may even be useable, I'm not sure.

Since I guess you probably can't wait and if the MultiDB branch isn't usable, here are your options.

- Follow [Eric Flows method](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/easy-multi-database-support-django/), bearing in mind that its not supported and new released of Django may break it. Also, some comments suggest its [already been broken](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/easy-multi-database-support-django/#dsq-time-13323576). This is going to be hacky.
- Your other option would be to use a totally different database access method for one of your databases. Perhaps [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for one and then Django ORM. I'm going by the guess that one is likely to be more Django centric and the other is a legacy database.

To summarise. I think hacking MultiDB into Django is probably the wrong way to go unless your prepared to keep up with maintaining your hacks later on. Therefore I think another ORM or database access would give you the cleanest route as then you are not going out with supported features and at the end of the day, its all just Python.

Comment: Looks like this has been commited to trunk now and has docs available too http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Yup. It sure has and its awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

My company has had success using multiple databases by closely following this blog post: http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/easy-multi-database-support-django/

Comment: Thanks Bluu I think I saw this before but not sure if I tried it or not.  My app is working with some helper methods that have their own mysql connection so this will have to wait for v2 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn`t the answer your looking for, but it`s probably best if you move everything you need into the one database.

Comment: Thanks spence, that's not really an option becuase I want to access the data from other applications like freeradius.