# In Django, how to control which DB connection and cursor a queryset will use

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to get a queryset to issue its query over a different DB connection, using a different cursor class.  Does anyone know if that's possible and if so how it might be done?  In psuedo-code:

```
  # setup a new db connection:
  db = db_connect(cursorclass=AlternateCursor)

  # setup a generic queryset
  qset = blah.objects.all()

  # tell qset to use the new connection:
  qset.use_db(db)

  # and then apply some filters
  qset = qset.filter(...)

  # and execute the query:
  for object in qset:
     ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: not really a duplicate, but the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779055/multiple-databases-in-django-1-0-2-with-custom-manager . In a nutshell: it's not really supported yet, but a GSOC project is/was working on it: http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/267a2fd7104f0209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible from Django 1.0 on - the trick is to use a custom manager for your model and replace the manager's connection object. See the code at Eric Florenzano's post at http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/easy-multi-database-support-django/